# Denoting a string in a function using colon

Tags: php, javascript

I am using a onclick function that stores a character in

```
 $itemid=1;
 $storeid=3;
 $status='rejected';

  <a class="blue" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="status('.$itemid.','.$storeid.','.$status.')" >
```

But right now it shows an error in firebug

```
  rejected is not defined

  status(1, 3, rejected);
```

My feeling is that it should pass the string - rejected as

```
status(1,3,'rejected')
```

I have tried to represent the function as shown below

```
 onclick="status('.$itemid.','.$storeid.','".$status."')
```

but its not working... Can any one suggest a solution for this please..

Comment: Please be more concise. You have not given any indication as to what is php, what is html, and what is javascript. Additionally, it appears that a bunch of quotes are incorrectly escaped. Finally, your example code is fragmented; it needs context. Please edit and fix and expect a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (note the backslash to escape the quote)

```
<a class="blue" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="status('.$itemid.','.$storeid.',\''.$status.'\')" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to properly create an escaped string:

```
onclick="status($itemid, $storeid, '.json_encode($status).")";
```

This requires PHP 5.2.0 and that the value of `$status` is valid UTF-8, but none of these should be a problem.

Comment: @Nabe: This is just an example of what to do. You haven't given a single line of code in its entirety, so it's not strange that there's a syntax error.